# Change color of text after reaching certain number limit?

Tags: flutter

I need to make a textfield that only accepts up to 100 (as string) maximum, if they type 101 or more it should turn red, can you do this in flutter with or without an outside package?

I have no idea where to even start, is the first time i do something this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this custom widget, remember I set the `limit` to 5 for test:

```
class CustomInput extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomInput({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomInput> createState() => _CustomInputState();
}

class _CustomInputState extends State<CustomInput> {
  Color textColor = Colors.black;
  int limit = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'some text'),
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.length > limit && textColor == Colors.black) {
          setState(() {
            textColor = Colors.red;
          });
        } else if (value.length <= limit && textColor == Colors.red) {
          setState(() {
            textColor = Colors.black;
          });
        }
      },
      style: TextStyle(
        color: textColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Scaffold(
  key: _key,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      CustomInput(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change the text color on the `TextField` if it exceeds 100 characters, you can do the following:

Every [`TextField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) has a [`style`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/style.html) property that accepts a `TextStyle()`. Simply set the `color` to red if the controller exceeds 100 characters.

Here's a complete runnable example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomTextField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return TextField(
      maxLength: 100,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Enter your text',
      ),
      onChanged: (text) {
        setState(() {
          // update the text color
          _controller.text = text;
        });
      },
      style: TextStyle(
        color: (_controller.text.length > 100) ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```